# Execute command when mouse is pluged/unpluged on GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, xorg, devices, mouse

Is it possible to have something like event handler for plugging unpluggig a mouse in Unix System? I want to have a script that will enable/disable touchpad but not only on startup (you can find solution for that using google) but whenever I plug/unplug the mouse (when the system is running). Is it possible?